# How do I append some text to a string and call it as a method?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

How can I make the following cucumber step prettier?

```
Then(/^I should see my (published|unpublished) project$/) do |published_state|

  if published_state == "published"
    project_name = published_name
  elsif published_state == "unpublished"
    project_name = unpublished_name 
  end

  page.should have_content(project_name)
end
```

The if statement in the middle is the problem for me but I need it to take the RegEx match and decide whether to call "published_name" or "unpublished_name". I was hoping to be able to do this instead:

```
Then(/^I should see my (published|unpublished) project$/) do |published_state|    
  page.should have_content(published_state + "_name")
end
```

I also tried the following:

```
page.send should_or_not, have_content("#{pub_state}_name".constantize)
page.send should_or_not, have_content("#{pub_state}_name".to_sym)
```

Basically I want to take a string "published", and append "_name" to it, and call that as a method.

Comment: Why the method `published_name` has no caller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably do something like:

```
Then(/^I should see my (published|unpublished) project$/) do |published_state|
  page.should have_content(send(:"#{published_state}_name"))
end
```

However, I would simply write:

```
Then /^I should see my published project$/ do
  page.should have_content(published_name)
end

Then /^I should see my unpublished project$/ do
  page.should have_content(unpublished_name)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I take your point about using separate methods, and I probably will. Cheers